# element-wise divison in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

is there any way of implementing an element-wise division in keras. What i'm searching for is some kind of merge-layer that divides two inputs element by element. 
But i didn't find anything like this in keras.
Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`Lambda` layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda):

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

input1 = ...
input2 = ...
result = Lambda(lambda inputs: inputs[0] / inputs[1])([input1, input2])
```